# DataValueField set Specific ID

Tags: asp.net, properties, shopping-cart

I have sort of a general question.

I am making a shopping cart for a project where I am selling electronics.  So, for example I am selling an iPhone and a Samsung Galaxy on the same "Phones.aspx" page, and I am assigning one single Radio Button to each.  This way, if the customer wants to add the iPhone, they check the iPhone radio button and hit the ADD button under the iPhone to add it to the cart.

I plan to the DataSourceId for RadioButton connected to my ObjectDataSource.  My question is, how do I specify in the RadioButton the single ID for the iPhone?  I know that using the DataValueField and setting that to Id, will specify all of the Ids for my table.  But what property do I use to specify the specific Id for the iPhone, or can I even do that?

Comment: Nevermind! I am just going to use SqlDataSource!

Answer (score 0):

With radio buttons, the value property is the one that differentiates within a group of radios. So you may see this:

```
<input type='radio' id='ID_product' value='iPhone'> iPhone &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='radio' id='ID_product' value='Samsung Galaxy'> Samsung Galaxy<br>
<br>
```